# how to use your network as a hotspot without losing internet connections

Tags: networking

I Have a system running Ubuntu 12.04 and I wanted to know if I could in any way make my computer a hot-spot. My device is home network EVDO/CDMA and I want to share the network usually with other Ubuntu and sometimes Windows computers. I have already tried `ap-hotspot` but it still doesn't work. I want to share the network without losing Internet access access for myself. Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yesthis is possible, but you need 2 network cards:

- One to access the big world (WWW)
- The other to make a local LAN.

Then you need to set your pc to act as a router to the internet.

Detailed instructions can be found on the [official Ubuntu site](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing).

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Try reading this fine tutorial: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing

Comment: could you please tell me step by step how to do that? please?

Comment: @KidusAmare: you don't need an additional WiFi card if you can hook up your cable to the router.  Then you can use your NIC to connect to the Internet and your WiFi card to play hotspot (if and only if your WiFi card can work as an AP, not all network cards can do that). BTW, the link that Ken provided **is a step-by-step** how-to...  Just start reading!

Comment: but I am using 12.04 and I have tried those methods before. the network shows up on other computers but there is no actual internet connection on either my or the other computer. and BTW, I dont have a router. but my computer does have a wifi card